# If $aX_1+bX_2+cX_3=0$ then find the partial correlation coefficients

Tags: regression, correlation, multiple-regression

> Suppose there are observations $X_{1i},X_{2i},X_{3i}$ with $i=1,2,...,n$. Suppose for every $i$, $aX_{1i}+bX_{2i}+cX_{3i}=0$ where $a,b,c$ are fixed constants of the same sign. Find the values of the partial correlation coefficients $r_{12.3},r_{13.2},r_{23.2}$.

I could not proceed much with the problem except only observing that the multiple correlation coefficient among $X_1,X_2,X_3$ is $1$ so $r_{12}^2+r_{23}^2+r_{13}^2-2r_{12}r_{13}r_{23}=1$. I know the formula for the partial correlation coefficients but I do not understand what to do next. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried solving a simpler problem? Say, $a=b=c=1$ for a simple discrete example?

Comment: If this is a homework question, please add a `self-study` tag and read its [Wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: This is not a homework question. Soakley, could you explain a bit more? I mean, whatever I may take, this equation does not at all seem to have any effect on the partial correlation coefficients.

Comment: What values are you finding for the partial correlation coefficients?

Comment: I think I mentioned that I am not finding any "different" value for the partial correlation coefficients than the standard expressions.

Comment: Create a population of your $X$ values that satisfy your constraint and compute the actual numerical values of the partial correlation coefficients. When I mentioned values, I meant computed numbers from the standard expressions.

Comment: Alright, I get your point. I have to attend a lecture today, so maybe later today I will give a reply to your comment after having simulated some Normal random variables satisfying this constraint.

Comment: I did simulate the situation and calculated the partial correlation coefficients but their values do not suggest any conspicuous relationship. They seem to be some just "calculated" values.

Answer (score 1):

The partial correlation $\rho_{12.3}$ measures the behavior of $X_1$ and $X_2$ when $X_3$ is held constant. If $X_3$ is fixed, then from your constraint it must be the case that $X_1$ and $X_2$ are perfectly negatively correlated as their sum must be constant. I am ignoring $a,$ $b,$ and $ c$ because they don't matter in terms of correlation.

A good example to work through is the Dirichlet distribution, where $X_1+X_2+X_3=1.$ After a couple of pages of algebra it can be shown that $\rho_{12.3}=\rho_{13.2}=\rho_{23.1}=-1.$